# Deleting Rows Based on Text Values in Specific Column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, delete-row

[image]
I have written a short macro to delete all rows that have a value of "Not Applicable" in column I, for the "Budget" tab of my workbook.

The macro does not seem to be doing anything when I run it through my testing:

```
Sub Remove_NA_Macro_Round_2()
    With Sheets("Budget") 'Applying this macro to the "Budget" sheet/tab.

        'Establishing our macro range parameters
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim i As Long

        'Setting the last row as the ending range for this macro
        LastRow = .Range("I50").End(xlUp).Row

        'Looping throughout all rows until the "LastRow" ending range set above
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If .Range("I" & i).Value = "Not Applicable" Then
                .Range("I" & i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Put a period before each instance of `Range`.

Comment: i think there is a "value" missing:   If Range("I" & i).value = "NA" Then

Comment: Get rid of the hard-coded `"I50"`. `LastRow` will then be `2` based on your screenshot. Instead, `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: @Hanman004 BigBen is right, because your first row is blank the `LastRow` value would be row 2.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, your method in detecting the `LastRow` was the solution! Please update your original answer and I will gladly mark this as the correct solution. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, when deleting rows based on a condition, it is faster to use a filter then looping.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With rng
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="Not Applicable"
        rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete 'deletes the visible rows below the first row
        .AutoFilter
    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Would this approach impact the order of my rows or would any blank rows interfere?

Comment: @Hanman004 First, you should always use unknown code on a copy of your data. When using AutoFilter, the criteria you are filtering will be the only row visible except for the first(header) row. When you shift the range down one row, and use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` only the visible rows are deleted. `.AutoFilter` then removes the filter and only the rows that did not have "Not Applicable" are left. This process is much faster then looping.

Comment: I am seeing your proposed method using a filter works as well. However, I am running into an issue when I test this where I have no values in columns `A` through `H` while `Not Applicable` is entered in column `I`. In other words, your proposed solution only seems to run when there is information filled out in the other columns. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Hanman004 Yes, `column A` is the normal column that will be filled completely, so `column A` is used to get the full count of the rows that have data. If you clear any cells in `column A` at the bottom of your range, those rows will not be counted in the range, so if you have "Not Applicable" in `column I` on those rows, they will not be deleted. You can just change the column that is used to count the rows. e.g. Change `Rows.Count, "A"` to `Rows.Count, "I"` when setting `rng`

Comment: This is great. I actually like this better now as it runs much faster. Approx. 26 seconds as opposed to 3 minutes for 5000+ rows. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please give @BigBen the check mark back, i was just providing an alternative approach.

Comment: Eh @GMalc keep it, this is a better approach anyway, I was just too lazy to actually throw it together.

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually referencing the `With Sheets("Budget")`. Add a period `.` before each instance of `Range`, otherwise there's an implicit `ActiveSheet`, which is not necessarily the Budget tab.

```
With Sheets("Budget") 
    ...

    LastRow = .Range("I50").End(xlUp).Row

    ...
        If .Range("I" & i).Value = "Not Applicable" Then
            .Range("I" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    ...

End With
```

**EDIT:**

Based on commentary and your provided screenshot, change how `LastRow` is determined (get rid of the hard-coded `I50`):

```
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the example. I was missing the ".Value" before the = "NA" and I added the periods. However, my macro still does not seem to be running. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Hanman004 are you sure the cell contains only `NA` and not any spaces or other characters either seen or unseen?

Comment: @Hanman004 I just ran your macro exactly as you have it above and it worked for me.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I have verified the cells I want to remove only contain "NA". I am creating a fresh (macro-enabled) workbook to test the above, but I am unsure why I am not seeing these rows being deleted.

Comment: @Hanman004 and the cell is text `NA` and not the error `#N/A`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, that is correct. Do you think the "NA" value is confusing the Macro's syntax? I can change the parameter word to something else. Perhaps I will do that to be clearer.

Comment: No, but try this: `If .Range("I" & i).Value Like "*NA*" Then` @Hanman004

Comment: @Hanman004 I tested your macro using numbers and the text `NA` in each cell, so for rows I wanted to test deleting, I had a `1` in each cell and `NA` in column I. After running the macro each row with `NA` in column I was deleted.

Comment: And one last question @Hanman004 are you sure the column is `I` and the sheet is `Budget`?

Comment: @ Tydis I performed the same test you described and it does not seem to be running for me. Perhaps this indicates an issue outside of my code.
@ScottCraner Correct, I have confirmed the column to be `I` and sheet to be named `Budget`

Comment: What is the value of `LastRow`? I wouldn't use a loop here but would rather filter and then delete visible rows.

Comment: @Hanman004 Could you copy and paste your macro code again so we can verify any issues?

Comment: @Tydis Sure, I'll upload an image of my test file too just in case.

Comment: @Hanman004 Are you clicking that button and nothing is happening? Try pressing alt + F8 and running the macro from that window and see what happens. If that works, right click the button and click assign macro and select your macro.

Comment: @Tydis Oddly, nothing is happening when I click the button I have assigned the macro for nor when I run the macro from the alt+F8 window. I'm assuming your test described previously looks similar to what I have done?

Comment: Have you adjusted how `LastRow` is determined yet?